# I'm making a decoder for bencode and I have been a while trying to get the info_hash of this:

Tags: php

I'm making a decoder for bencode and I have been a while trying to get the info_hash of this:

`d10:created by18:qBittorrent v4.2.513:creation datei1617086975e4:infod6:lengthi6e4:name10:asdasd.txt12:piece lengthi16384e6:pieces20:�ly���6���c�p�e��7ee`

https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification

I have read that article 3 times and still, I can't figure out what I'm supposed to make a sha1 to get the info_hash. I will appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: `info_hash: 20-byte SHA1 hash of the info key in the metainfo file.`.

Comment: `d6:lengthi6e4:name10:asdasd.txt12:piece lengthi16384e6:pieces20:�ly���6���c�p�e��7e` Should I make a sha1 of that right?

Comment: When in doubt read the source of someone else's implementation.

Comment: Yes, that part should be the content of the `info` dictionary. It starts after the `d`, and ends before the last `e`.

Comment: I tried doing that but It does not give me the correct info hash.